# want to find documents range x minutes results on time-stamp linux

Tags: python, pymongo, pypy

I want to get results behalf of timestamp stored in mongodb document named 
like:
time: 1479300769

I am using pypy and pymongo

time range should be x minutes or x hours

delete documents suing same criteria after fetching results

Here is the code:

startTime and endTime should be a time stamp linux

```
import time
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
startTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes)
endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
appConnection = MongoClient("127.0.0.1",27017)
db = appConnection.db
db.collection.find({"time":{"$gt":startTime,"$lte":endTime}})
```

but its not working...

Thanks in advance :

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: added code which I had tried to get mongo records

Comment: can you describe the way in which this does not work? Does it just return zero documents? Does it throw an error?

Comment: yes its returns zero documents even documents exist on that time span